# How to define a custom "names<-" function in R?

Tags: r, function, names

I am trying to create a custom "names<-" function for my class. Using just

```
names(object_of_my_class)
```

works for reading names, but if I try to assign new names like this:

```
names(object_of_my_class) <- c(...)
```

just turns the "object_of_my_class" into NULL.

Anyone has ideas on how to define the names function, so that it works in the 2nd instance?

Comment: \`names<-.my_class\` <- function

Comment: You can see how others have done this with, e.g. `zoo:::\`names<-.zoo\``

Comment: @nrussell or `methods("names<-")` for the laundry list

Comment: @MichaelChirico True, I was mostly suggesting that OP should look at the actual function body for reference though.

Comment: @nrussell I'm with you, just adding more options of functions to examine

Comment: Wow, guys, you're quick. Thank you @MichaelChirico - this works.